# How to stop car steaming up?

Tags: hvac, opel, agila

My 2003 Opel Agila always seems to steam up constantly while driving, in all weathers. I do not have a damp problem in the car either, everywhere seems dry.

I have checked the following things:

- Air selector is **not** on recirculate mode
- Heating works, and the fan is fine (seems to run okay, good airflow)

I don't have AC so I can't leave this running to dehumidify the air.

I have even bought a 12v dehumidifier to try and solve the problem, but this doesn't seem to work that well.

I always have to drive with the heater on full, which makes the car unbearably hot, or drive with the window wide open, which makes the car very cold.

**Is there anything I can do to stop my windows misting up while driving?**

Comment: Is the car losing coolant at all?  A pin-hole in the heater core could cause excess moisture in the cabin.

Comment: I am with @JPhi1618 on this. Whenever I have experienced extreme misting, it has either been water ingress, or a leaking heater matrix.

Comment: To me, this sounds like recirculate mode. Are you sure the mechanism is working? (do you notice smells from outside?)

Comment: @sweber How do I check for recirculate mode problems?

Comment: @jphi1618, I'll top up the coolant and check

Comment: If the heater blower does not help - do check if you have a cabin filter installed. Check it's condition if you do, might be the cause of extreme misting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try just driving with a window open a crack to allow the inside to breath a little bit. It's your breath which usually causes the windshield to mist up.

Also, use a product like [Rain-X Anti-Fog](http://www.carid.com/rain-x/anti-fog-mpn-af21106d.html). By ensuring your windshield is first clean and then by applying the product, there is nothing for the humidity to stick to, so no fog.